# htaccess subdomain pointing

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

I need some help on the htaccess subdomain to be pointed to specific file in a folder.

Inside the parent folder should contain individual php files to correctly path the right applications. Sounds simple here.

**The url that the user has type should not change / redirect, instead it should only
"link" to the correct file at the background**

Example when user type `userbase.company.com` it should point to

```
http://company.com/parent/userbase.php
```

Similarly, when user type `userbase2.company.com` it should point to

```
http://company.com/parent/userbase2.php
```

but no redirection should happen. url links should remain at

```
http://userbase2.company.com
```

folder would be the same, but not the file. Is it possible?

Currently I have this htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^userbase.company.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.userbase.company.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ \./parent/userbase.php/$1 [L]
```

I'm going have to put this at `/public_folder/` right? Not at the `/public_folder/userbase` ?

Comment: 1) What is `\./parent/`? Why there is a dot `.` in front? 2) Does subdomain pointing to the same folder as main domain or what? 3) Are these subdomains have limited numbers (e.g. `userbase` & `userbase2`) or it can be any name? 4) If user requests this URL  (for example): `http://user1.company.com/hello/pink/kitten.php` it should be rewritten (no redirect) to `http://company.com/parent/user1.php/hello/pink/kitten.php`, right? (based on your current rules).

Comment: 1. the dot is irrelevant, i was only trying to point it to the sub folder but its wrong. 2. the subdomain is not pointed to any folder inside it, but main domain (company.com) points to single folder, but multiple file names (ex. 'userbase1.php, userbase2.php', etc.). The reason here is that every subdomain runs as independent application. 3. subdomains are unlimited and at any word. 4.Yes,'http://company.com/parent/user1.php/hello/pink/kitten.php' is the correct url, but please note user must not be redirected by changing the browser url. Also 'user1.php' is arbitrary per subdomain

Comment: You might get confuse on my narrative explaination, but I have put a visual illustration here so that it can be visually understood easier. Please refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746143/running-multiple-application-for-codeigniter-htaccess-issue Thank you. :)

Comment: I have no problems with creating a rule .. but I would like to clarify #2. Subdomains have to point somewhere. most likely they are aliases of the main domain (site can accept ANY subdomain) -- this means they are pointed to website root folder. I do not want to write a rule and answer just to find out that your setup is completely different.

Comment: I think I know what you mean, your looking for a folder path in which you could route the RewriteRule to a particular folder, since subdomains can't be routed to a file. Well, we can route it to /parent/userbase1, /parent/userbase2, /parent/userbase3. And this just came into me that, probably CI index can route it by changing the application path on subdomains, which I'll try to explore right now. But yeah, I'm fine with adding extra folders in /parent/ for the purpose of this htaccess issue.

Comment: No .. that's not what I have had in mind. I will post my solution .. and you check if it works for you.

Comment: Okey, I'll wait for it then. Regarding the CI's system_path routing to particular folder from subdomain to main domain seems to be not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This rule should do the job:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/parent/ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) /parent/%1.php%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

1. URL will remain unchanged in browser (means rewrite -- internal redirect).
2. It will only work for `something.domain.com` (not `domain.com` or `www.domain.com`).
3. It will rewrite this request `http://user1.company.com/hello/pink/kitten.php` into `/parent/user1.php/hello/pink/kitten.php`
4. If subdomain is complex (e.g. `www.something.domain.com`) then it will be reflected in rewrite as well: e.g. `http://www.something.company.com/hello/pink/kitten.php` will be rewritten to `/parent/www.something.php/hello/pink/kitten.php`. If such behaviour is undesired (I do not know your requirements for 100%) then you will need add 1 more condition to the rule.
5. Request for a home page (e.g. `http://user1.company.com/`) will be rewritten in this way: `/parent/user1.php/`

**P.S.**
Rule was tested before posting -- works fine, but you have to check and maybe tweak it if it needs to be working with your CodeIgniter app (sorry, I'm not familiar with that framework).

In any case this rule should be **above** your CodeIgniter rewrite rules (if there are such).

Comment: Hi this works fine too with my requirement. Yup I think I can do the rest regarding the framework thing. But this meets the requirements of subdomain rewriting! Thanks much LazyOne, appreciate it!