# All subdomains point to a file with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Tried a couple things, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6844715/502649) I'm trying the code below, but it's not working.
Actually when I try to use, its shows the hosting panel page.

I'm using my own server, for administration [ispCP](http://isp-control.net/) is installed.

What I'm trying to do is, except original domain and www, redirect all sub domains to a php file.

```
Options -MultiViews
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/parent/ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) /subpage.php?page=%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServerAlias config fixed my problem. Appearently i was needed a wildcard.
which is ***.domain.com**

```
ServerAlias www.domain.com domain.com *.domain.com
```