# htaccess subdomain with subfolders access

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite the subdomain request to a subfolder in my server using `.htaccess`. I want `mail.domain.com` to look into `mail` folder located in the root. I am able to achieve this with the below code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mail.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mail
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mail/$1 [L]
```

This WORKS correctly. When i browse to `mail.domain.com` i am getting the contents of `domain.com/mail/index.php`.

However this doesn't work with the subfolders inside the subdomain. ie when i browse to `mail.domain.com/installer` it DOESN'T give the contents from `domain.com/mail/installer/index.php`. Instead it shows 404 error. I also tried the code from [htaccess subdomain pointing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831091/htaccess-subdomain-pointing) . Somehow I am unable to get the output. That method also gives the same problem. What am I doing wrong?

Note:

1. I do not want redirect conditions. Want to achieve via rewrite rules.
2. I am using openshift server. created `domain.com` & `mail.domain.com` aliases.
3. Root folder contains wordpress with <strike>no</strike> below .htaccess rules.

**Edit**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

When I remove the above wordpress htaccess all works well. So it is causing 404 error in subdomain subfolders. Please help what i can do for both wordpress pretty urls and subdomain subfolders to work?

Note: I am really sorry. Wordpress added this via web interface and i failed to notice that.

Comment: try adding this rule `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

Comment: @Kamran I tried that. Now `mail.domain.com` shows content from `domain.com`

Comment: @anubhava Yes. I tried that. `mail.domain.com/installer/` gives 404 error :(

Comment: Can you [set up the Virtual Host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost) in the config of httpd instead of using `.htaccess`?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ I do not have access to edit Virtual hosts file in the server. So i am trying with htaccess method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your root .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =mail.domain.com
RewriteRule ^((?!mail).*)$ mail/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(index\.php$|mail) - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Awesome. Working. Can you please explain what is happening in each line and what was the problem? Thank you very much. Saved my day

Comment: Actually most of it is your own rule. Only difference is first rule that uses `(?!mail)` a negative lookahead to forward only to `mail/` only if it is not already starting with `/mail/`. Then 2nd rule `RewriteRule ^(index\.php$|mail) - [L,NC]` will ignore `index.php` or `/mail/` from WP default rule.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much